# Select a column within a Filtered range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a column within a filtered range, but it keeps selecting the first cell instead. I have the table already filtered out, just need to select the actual column (column E), minus the header.

This is currently what I have:

```
            'After sorting, we will end up with several data rows for
            'which we will need to sort from. Now that we have a filtered table,
            'we would then need to created a variable for our new filtered range
            Dim DeliverableTablefltrdRng As Range
            Set DeliverableTablefltrdRng = rRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            'Now that we have all these sorted, we will then need to
            'verify whether the target finish date is within the start and end date
            
            Dim WorkOrderRange As Range

            Set WorkOrderRange = DeliverableTablefltrdRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

Comment: are you looking for something like that:         ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:$E$" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 9).End(xlUp).Row).Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*run*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to previously extract the visible cells range. Please, test the next way:

```
Sub testSelectVisColRange()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, WorkOrderRange As Range
  
 'your code filterring...
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   Set WorkOrderRange = sh.Range("E2:E" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   WorkOrderRange.Select
End Sub
```

The code should have a (simple) way of dealing with the error raised in case of no any visible cell, but this is only an example, showing the way to be followed...

Comment: @RawrRawr7: Didn't my above code solve your problem?